# How to get the json value with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
<li>
    <input name="select_address" type="radio">
    <span><?php echo Form::hidden('values', json_encode($arr));?></span>
</li>
```

I use the following code to get the encoded $arr,but not working.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        $('table').removeAttr('hidden');
        console.log($(this).next().html());
    });
```

Comment: You have a missing closing `)` sigh after `json_encode`

Comment: Please post your complete HTML so we can help you.

Comment: You are jumping through unnecessary hoops. Why serve the data into the DOM? To be of any use, it's going to end up in javascript, so serve it directly as eg `var = <?php ... ?>` between `<script>...</script>` tags.

Comment: the $arr is one of the arrays which in foreach. I have to foreach it first and then get the value by jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `val()` to get value from your hidden input. You would then need to parse the string to javascript object/array.

Another clean approach is to set the json in a `data-` attribute and let jQuery read it form the data attribute

```
<li>
    <input name="select_address" type="radio" data-myData='<?=json_encode($arr)?>'>    
</li>
```

.

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){      
    console.log($(this).data('myData'));
});
```

When properly formatted json is passed to a `data-` attribute, jQuery `data()` method will already handle it as an object or array

Reference: [**data() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)